# Keyboard behaving erratically

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Every time I press <kbd>E</kbd>, a new window pops up. Whenever I press <kbd>T</kbd>, a tab pops up. I don’t understand what is happening. I can’t type or anything (I am typing this question on my phone). Have I accidentally activated something?

What is happening and how can I get it to stop?

Answer (score 2):

See if the Windows or Ctrl key is stuck. Win+E opens a new explorer window and Ctrl+T opens a new tab.

Comment: I don't have a windows key - it fell of and I ripped the contacts out. This never used to happen before, why is it happening now? Is there something in the system prefs?

Comment: Could the contacts have shorted? Or possibly a wireless KB causing issues? That's about all I can think of.

Comment: So you're saying your keyboard has the equivalent of an open wound and you're wondering why you're seeing strange behavior from it?  Buy a new keyboard.  And be sure to shoot your old one in the head, lest it bite the new one and start the Keyboard Zombie Apocalypse.

Answer (score 1):

lexvegas is correct; it sounds like one of your modifier keys is stuck (most likely the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key based on your description).

Obviously, this can happen through mechanical means such as the key getting physically stuck from a sticky liquid, dust, paper, etc. Check that nothing has fallen in and that the key physically move up and down freely.

Another reason that a modifier key can get stuck is from software. Sometimes when you are holding down a key and the active window changes in just the right way, the *key-up* message (`WM_KEYUP`) that is normally sent when a key is released can get lost and/or misdirected, which then causes the system to think that it is still being held down.

Try pressing it a few times to release the key. If it is a software lock, then simply pressing and releasing it should resolve the problem. If it is a physically problem, then you will notice that it doesn’t pop back up (or go down in the first place) and can then address it. Either way, make sure to test *both* keys since most keyboards have *left and right* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> keys. (in fact, whenever I notice any strange keyboard behavior, I instinctively just mash each of the eight—four pairs—of modifiers a couple of times).